# Second clearInterval not working to stop the function from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 js functions - one of them is in global `main.js` file and another one is local to one of my html pages `<script>` tags. I have access to `main.js` in all files simply because they are being loaded in the `main.html` page via ajax. I am able to stop the main function from `clearInterval` in my html page but when I am trying to do `clearInterval` for the local function, somehow its not working.

The `clearIntervals` get triggered when I click the 'edit' button of the page. But my problem is when I click 'edit' only the global function gets stopped but not the local one. The function is just updating `selectmenu` options based on values that are being recieved from the server. For `textboxes` it updates in real time but for `selectmenus` I had to use this approach to make it work in real time.

Below is the JS code with local function:

```js
var dropdown_update=setInterval(updateDropdownValues, 1200); //calling the local function

function updateDropdownValues(){

    //does some work

}

$("#editFields").click(function(){

    //some code
    clearInterval(ajax_interval); //works..ajax_interval is in main.js not shown here
    clearInterval(dropdown_update); //doesnt work..keeps executing the function

});
```

Following is `main.js` relevant part (I dont think this is the culprit):

```js
var ajax_interval = setInterval(loadAjaxData2, 1 * 1000);

function loadAjaxData2() {
   //some variables
    $.ajax({
        //an ajax call
    });

}
```

I looked over several stackoverflow posts but none of them had this kind of problem.

Comment: honestly i dont think main.js thing is causing the problem because that is working fine I just wanted to give the context. However, I will remove other code. Let me edit it

Comment: Yes, main.js doesn't have the problem, but it would be helpful to see how it's different from the code that isn't working :)

Comment: @4castle : ok i will just add that part as well

Comment: @4castle: I just made edit

Comment: Is the `dropdown_update` variable in the same scope as `ajax_interval` ?
For what I see, `dropdown_update` is inside another callback (since you are declaring a jQuery click listener, I assume it's inside some kind of onLoad or onReady block).   Try separating the declaration of `var dropdown_update` (in global scope) and the assignation of the interval handler as you have it.

Comment: I moved the var dropdown_update to main.js and assigned it here but still the result is the same. It just doesnt stop